# Should I make email in database not unique if I have social login like facebook and google?

Tags: php, database, laravel, web, database-design

What if the user use the same email address with their facebook and google account then my email in database is unique. I cant let the user login if they already login with either facebook or google. How can I handle this things? Thank you

Comment: this question is too vague and opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think email address should be unique in database
Then all of login methods refer to same account
`name.one@gmail.com` > `google` ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ > `user6`
`name.one@gmail.com` > `facebook` > `user6`

If they already login with either facebook or google,
**Should bypass login page and auto redirect to login area**.

But another important thing before insert into database is that
`nameone@gmail.com` == `name.one@gmail.com` 
`nameone@gmail.com` == `na.me.one@gmail.com` 
`nameone@gmail.com` == `n.ameone@gmail.com` 

Then its better to strip dots before insert